# Change tab height in a TabView?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabview

Is it possible to change the size of the tabs displayed in a `TabActivity`? I'm currently only putting text in my tabs and I'd really like to minimize the size as much as possible.

Also, is there a way to use icons for my activity that aren't 48x48? I'd like to do something more rectangular as opposed to square. I just want to use my screen real-estate the best I can :)

How is the YouTube app doing this? (See screenshot, and *yes* I know that the YouTube app isn't open source)

[image]
[image]

It seems that they're also making it possible to scroll left and right for more tabs. Any ideas on how they're doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yest you can do all that by  creating your own custom view for tab widget, it is quite simple to do. this tutorial will do the trick

http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136